# Are too many pipes bad for performance

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I use that bash command to search files and execute md5dsum on my local system. In my opinion this command has bad performance on large `vendor` directories. Is there a better style instead of using pipe after pipe with higher performance?

```
find ./vendor -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 md5sum | grep -vf /usr/local/bin/vchecker_ignore > MD5sums
```

Comment: I don't think pipes are too costly; they are much better than starting a process for each input line.

Comment: Also, exclude the undesired files (those listed in vchecker_ignore) in the very first step instead of processing them first only to throw them away later.

Comment: `they are much better than starting a process for each input line.`. What do you mean? How does it make sense to run sort on each input line (for example)? I think you are mixing something

Comment: pipes itself are no performance problem at all. The only problem here is that you calculate checksums for files which you filter out anyway afterwards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sort` introduces blocking here: it has to wait till `find` completed before outputting its results. `find` on a large filesystem, especially with hdd or nfs, may take a while.

You may like to sort at the very end to allow `md5sum` to run in parallel with `find`, e.g.:

```
find ./vendor -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum | grep -vf /usr/local/bin/vchecker_ignore | sort -k2 > MD5sums
```

`md5sum` may take some time for large files. You may like to run it with GNU `parallel` instead of `xargs` if there are many files or files are large.

---

You may also like to play with line-buffered mode. In this case it needs to use new-line delimiters for filenames (that prohibits new-line symbols in filenames, which would be rather unusual) instead of 0-delimiter for line-buffered mode to work. E.g.:

```
stdbuf -oL find ./vendor -type f | stdbuf -oL grep -vf /usr/local/bin/vchecker_ignore | xargs -n50 -d'\n' md5sum | sort -k2 > MD5sums
```

The above command is going to filter each file through that `grep` first and then execute `md5sum` on batches of 50 files. For small files you may like larger batches (and may be remove both `stdbuf -oL` completely), for large files - smaller.

Comment: One could sort *after* the md5sum call (by column 2, the file name output of md5sum); this would ideally allow the hash computation to start while the search is still running; one is disk, the other one is CPU, so there may be a real benefit. Perhaps one should use `unbuffer` or `stdbuf` (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe) to let md5sum start immediately.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Yep, line-buffered `find` into `parallel md5sum` and then collect, filter and sort `md5sum` outputs.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Thinking more about buffering, the command uses 0-separators, so that line-buffered mode won't affect it.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin You can use a buffer size of 0 instead of line buffered if you want that.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest to use `xargs` like that. newlines in filenames would break it. Well, the fact that the OP is using `grep -vf` to filter out filenames makes the solution (in the question) vulnerable to newlines in filenames anyway.

Comment: At the end the usage of md5sum for files which can contain newlines is just broken because it is replacing the newline with `\n` making it impossible to say if that filename literally contained `\n` or a newline.

Comment: Having that you can probably just use `find ... -exec md5sum {} + | grep -vf ...` - without the stdbuf magic.

Comment: @hek2mgl _I wouldn't suggest to use `xargs` like that. newlines in filenames would break it._ - if you have newlines in filenames you may have a bigger problem.

Comment: @hek2mgl With `find ... -exec md5sum {} +` you do not have control of how many filenames are passed to `md5sum`. If files are large you want fewer, if small - more. Also, I am not sure if `find` blocks while it does `-exec`, whereas with `| xargs` it does not block.

Comment: @hek2mgl _You can use a buffer size of 0 instead of line buffered if you want that._ - I am unlikely to want that. I want filenames without newlines (pretty reasonable) and line-buffered mode.

Comment: *If files are large you want fewer* why? About newlines in filenames. Take into account that you can't always control the input. Especially If the tool is about to be released to the public. But also read what I wrote about md5sum and newlines in filenames.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin thank you! I think the second command with stdbuf is pretty fast.